# How to show saturation map (w.r.t quasicoherent sheaves) isnt always injective / surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coherent-sheaves, quasicoherent-sheaves

This question is motivated by problem 15.4.D(a) in Vakil, but to give some setup since the notation / terminology may differ: let $S_\bullet$ be a nice graded algebra (finitely generated, generated in degree 1) and $M_\bullet$ a graded $S_\bullet$-module.

The functor $\sim$ gives a natural way to turn $M_\bullet$ into a quasicoherent sheaf $\widetilde{M_\bullet}$ on $\operatorname{Proj} S_\bullet$ defined by
$$
\Gamma(D(f), \widetilde{M_\bullet}) = ((M_\bullet)_f)_0
$$

(where the first subscript is localization and the latter is the 0th graded piece).
This extends to the sheaves $ \widetilde{ M_\bullet (n) }$ via
$$
\Gamma(D(f), \widetilde{M_\bullet (n)}) = ((M_\bullet)_f)_n
$$

We obtain the saturation map $ M_\bullet \to \Gamma_\bullet(\widetilde{M_\bullet})$ where
$$
\Gamma_n(\widetilde{M_\bullet}) = \Gamma(\operatorname{Proj} S_\bullet, \widetilde{M_\bullet (n)})
$$

This is indeed a (functorial) map of $S_\bullet$-modules since we always get a map
$$
M_n \to (( M_\bullet(n) )_g)_0 \hspace{3em} x \mapsto \frac{x}{1}
$$

for any $g \in S_+$, which induces the map $M_n \to \Gamma (\operatorname{Proj} S_\bullet, \widetilde{M_\bullet (n)} )$ . However, my main confusion is that Vakil says it is only in nice situations that
$$
M_n \cong \Gamma ( \operatorname{Proj} S_\bullet, \widetilde{M_\bullet (n)} )
$$

so I'm not really sure how to interpret global sections in "not nice" scenarios. In particular, Vakil mentions that taking $S_\bullet = k[x]$ and either $M_\bullet = k[x]/ (x^2)$ or $M_\bullet = xk[x]$ we can show that the saturation map is neither injective nor surjective. Maybe there's just too much notation going on, but why is the map
$$
k[x]/(x^2) \to (( k[x]/(x^2) )_x)_0
$$
not just inducing the usual $ x \mapsto \frac{x}{1} $ ?

Comment: $(k[x]/(x^2))_x=0$, because you get the zero ring when you invert a nilpotent element